# Discord bot’s bio not changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

I've searched for so long, yet no result helped me set my bot's bio. The problem I'm encountering is that whatever I try to set the bio as it always returns an empty string. When I tried to set the username, it worked normally how it should, but its not setting the bio.

Code that I use to set the bio:

```js
 if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}bio`)) {
    console.log("Message Triggered.");
    var bio = message.content.slice(4);
    axios({
        method: "patch",
        url: "https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me",
        headers: {
            authorization: "Bot MyToken",
        },
        data: {
            bio: `My amazing bio!`,
        },
    })
        .then(({ data }) => console.log(1, data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

What the console returns:

```
{
  id: 'Bot ID',
  username: 'Bot Name',
  avatar: null,
  avatar_decoration: null,
  discriminator: '0535',
  public_flags: 0,
  flags: 0,
  bot: true,
  banner: null,
  banner_color: null,
  accent_color: null,
  > bio: '',
  token: 'MyTokenAgain',
  locale: 'en-US',
  mfa_enabled: true,
  email: null,
  verified: true
}
```

What it should return:

```
{
  id: 'Bot ID',
  username: 'Bot Name',
  avatar: null,
  avatar_decoration: null,
  discriminator: '0535',
  public_flags: 0,
  flags: 0,
  bot: true,
  banner: null,
  banner_color: null,
  accent_color: null,
  > bio: 'My amazing bio!',
  token: 'MyTokenAgain',
  locale: 'en-US',
  mfa_enabled: true,
  email: null,
  verified: true
}
```

I have no idea why it doesn't set the bio, as I have seen that it worked for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the About Me section on the bot profile, simply head over to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers), select your application and edit the "Description" field. This will appear in your Bot's about me section. [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfdAU.png)

### **Edit**

The About Me section on a bot's profile is not suitable for displaying information that changes regularly such as info about a certain song that's playing, ... because users would continuously need to refresh their clients to reload the cache and see the changes made.

I would suggest a dedicated channel with a message that you can edit or simply a /info command.

Comment: The problem in that is that I'm trying to make a radio bot, but some music needs to have like, stuff in description, so I want to give credits in the about me, so you know I won't be going over to about me every 5 minutes to change the about me. (Sorry if I should say this earlier, I don't post here very often..)

Comment: @TheAdministrator Users would have to constantly restart their Discord Client to clear the cache and see the updated About Me so you should probably move that to the bot's status if possible. You will also be rate limited after changing the About Me too often. Maybe consider a /info command or a pinned message that's being edited in a dedicated channel.